# replace string in cell range with part of the original text

Tags: excel, text, replace, range, vba

I have an excel sheet with a column for Car number.  It is currently downloaded as a report with the format "58 58" for car number 58.

I would like to replace each occurrence down column H and replace "58 58" with a numeric "58" | "60 60" with "a numeric "60" | "90 90" with a numeric "90" and so on.

This is all done in VBA.

Thank you

UPDATED CODE:
Dim X As Long
For X = 2 To Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Change 1 to 2 if you have a heading in row 1
    Range("I" & X).Formula = Split(Range("I" & X).Text, " ")(0)

I used the above code, but it gave me runtime error (9) subscript out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to loop. Going backwards alleviates possible issues with 101 being messed up if you start at 1.

```
Sub DoubleToSingle()
Dim X As Long
For X = 100 To 1 Step -1
    Cells.Replace X & " " & X, X
Next
End Sub
```

This works on all cells, if you want it on just a column replace Cells. with Columns(2). where 2 is column B and 3 would be C etc.

Edit: use this code for your updated questions:

```
Sub DoubleToSingle2()
Dim X As Long
For X = 2 To Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(1, Range("I" & X).text, " ") > 0 Then Range("I" & X).Formula = Split(Range("I" & X).text, " ")(0)
Next
End Sub
```

How it works: It polls through all cells in column I that have data and for each cell it splits the text of the cell into an array using space, then it takes just the first element in the array (basically everything before the first space) and posts that back to the cell.

Comment: Awesome!...worked as expected without a glitch... Thank you so much for the super quick response.  I only have one more issue that came up...for the same column, if a driver rejects a job, it will be recorded as "58 58 Rejects".  Applying the code above reduces that to "58 Rejects".  Now this only happens in lets say 3 lines out of 50, however, it is an unexpected result as the column in the database expects only "58".  So the question is how can we get rid of the "rejects" word when it does appear?

Comment: Also, I found cells that say "58 58 60, timeout"  I would need that reduced to just "58"

Comment: Use the updated code in my original post to cover both questions.

Comment: so here is the code i ended up with:   Dim X As Long
For X = 2 To Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Change 1 to 2 if you have a heading in row 1
    Range("I" & X).Formula = Split(Range("I" & X).Text, " ")(0)
Next     ..... however, that is giving me a runtime error 9, subscript out of range.....I am sure I am missing something

Comment: Can you edit your original question and post the code, comments don't allow me to see where the line breaks are. I have updated mine to use column I instead for you

Comment: Fixed, you have some cells which don't fit the criteria, you can't split on a space when none exists. Use the updated code in my original answer

Comment: Well...go figure, i must have done something wrong...using your edits worked like a charm!  Thank you again, you saved me a lot of headache

Comment: Nah mate it wasn't anything you did wrong, I added this If InStr(1, Range("I" & X).text, " ") > 0 Then as a test, without that it gives the error you had, this tells it to only try the split if there is at least one space in there somewhere :)

Comment: I am new to this awesome community, so I want to make sure that I don't break any forum rules, but is there a way I can buy you a drink or something as a sign of gratitude?

Comment: Just the sentiment is enough, the best thing you can do when anyone teaches you something is try and learn "why and how" it works, and keep posting questions whenever you don't understand :). Read through other peoples questions and if there is stuff in there you don't understand, ask questions :)